# New hire after internship, no task given by management

Tags: work-environment, work-experience

So I've been doing an internship at this company, I've tried to do my best and learn the maximum as possible so that they would hire me in the end of the sixth months internship, and they did.

I've integrated the same team i was working on with, as much as i really wanted to change the project, for the only reason that the team was not motivated to work, and that i'm a hard worker by nature, I couldn't find a way before the internship. So anyway, the project is now being shutdown and everyone in my team either was relocated to another project or left the company.

I've talked to the manager and promised to give me another opportunity in another project. But I've been coming for a month now everyday at time without any feedback from the management, eager to work and learn, doing nothing all day, I kind of feel stuck because i really need this job for financial matters.

Management always seems busy and unavailable, and i'm sure that i was forgotten in my corner... What should i do ? i'm really getting depressed and angry at the same time for this situation.. I kind of feel like a third wheel or even a backup wheel, any advice ?

Comment: @YElm Thanks for your suggestion , but i really want to kill time , i want to work with a team

Comment: There are more questions like yours that have been answered before. Have a look at [New Job: No Task Assigned Yet](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/116571/new-job-no-task-assigned-yet), [Dealing with lack of work in new job](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/36762/dealing-with-lack-of-work-in-new-job-efficiently-and-professionally) or [How can I be more “proactive” at my job?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/115974/how-can-i-be-more-proactive-at-my-job).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good way to phrase it is to ask your manager for a list of immediate priorities. Face to face would be best, but if it's hard to arrange time with your manager, an e-mail would serve. This gives you the opportunity to raise it again in a week or a month, and would be a good basis for the regular feedback you want.

This might be partly a question of management style - your manager might be thinking that unless people bring him/her issues everything is fine. This approach doesn't seem to be working for you, so it's worth bringing this to their attention.

Comment: I've sent an email for a face to face meeting , still waiting for a response , but thanks for your advice